# Issue creating Token Contract

Tags: solidity, tokens, remix, rinkeby

I am having an issue creating a contract on the Ethereum test net. I am getting the following warning statement:

sol:21:5: Warning: Defining constructors as functions with the same name as the contract is deprecated. Use "constructor(...) { ... }" instead.

Answer (score 2):

As of Solidity version 4.23, you should be using

```
constructor() {
  //...
}
```

Instead of

```
function MyContract() {
  //...
}
```