# Correcting Code for Constructor

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, constructor

[This StackExchange question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47291/issue-creating-token-contract) ALMOST answered my question. However I don't know how to exactly correct my code so that the function named after the contract is replaced by the constructor.

How specifically would this function be corrected?

```
contract Fake_Smrt_Coin is EIC20{

uint256 constant private MAX_UINT256 = 2**256 - 1;
mapping (address => uint256) public balances;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowed;

string public name;                   
uint8 public decimals;              
string public symbol;                 
//I know this line needs improvement
function Fake_Smrt_Coin (
    uint256 _initialAmount,
    string _tokenName,
    uint8 _decimalUnits,
    string _tokenSymbol
) public {
    balances[msg.sender] = _initialAmount;
    totalSupply = _initialAmount;
    name = _tokenName;
    decimals = _decimalUnits;
    symbol = _tokenSymbol;
}

function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value);
    balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
    balances[_to] += _value;
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value); 
    return true;
}
```

Would the updated code be?

```
  constructor(){
    string public name;                   
    uint8 public decimals;              
    string public symbol;                    
    }

function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value);
    balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
    balances[_to] += _value;
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value); 
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//I know this line needs improvement
constructor (
    uint256 _initialAmount,
    string _tokenName,
    uint8 _decimalUnits,
    string _tokenSymbol
) public {
    balances[msg.sender] = _initialAmount;
    totalSupply = _initialAmount;
    name = _tokenName;
    decimals = _decimalUnits;
    symbol = _tokenSymbol;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I had my parenthesis wrong with the public declaration. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `function Fake_Smrt_Coin` by the codeword `constructor`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I would give you tick, but I don't have the clout on this forum. The other answer gave a little more clarity. Thanks for your patience.